# regex recursive search python

Tags: python, regex, search, recursion

I'm experiencing some troubles with regex expressions in Python.
I'm trying to do a recursive search without using the searchall() method because I want to do some actions before catching the other match.

*Parser.py*

```
self._task_global = '(\*+)([\w\s\dàé]+)(<[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+>)?'

..... /* some crazy stuff here */ ....

tasks = self._task_global.search(text)
    while tasks != None:
        print tasks.groups()
        print tasks.endpos
        tasks = self._task_global.search(text, tasks.endpos)

    print tasks
```

This parser is supposed to match an orgfile, this is an example of orgfile task syntax.

*Test.org*

```
* Apprendre à me servir de orgmode

** DONE Faire un script en python pour tester pygit2 :gd: :bfgd: #1215454
```

The problem is my parser returning the first match but then 'None'. Is it a problem with the endpos value?

*The output*

```
('*', ' Apprendre \xc3\xa0 me servir de orgmode\n\n', None)
580
None
```

Thanks :3

Comment: I think self._task_global is a _sre.SRE_Pattern object but not a string, since string doesn't have search function.

Comment: And you need to tell details about function self._task_global.search().

Comment: @m170897017 In fact, I forgot to put one line in my question : `self._task_global = '(\*+)([\w\s\dàé]+)(<[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+>)?' self._task_global = re.compile(self._task_global, re.UNICODE)` . The search() function is the function for python regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<match>.endpos`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.endpos) will be either

- The integer you specify as an argument to the `match` or `search` call that produced the `<match>` MatchObject, *or*
- The length of the input string (i.e. `len(text)`)

Since you're not specifying an `endpos` argument ever, it will be = `len(text)`.  So the first iteration of the loop works fine, but the second is called with a `pos` that is too high, causing `search` to be (effectively) called on an empty string -- so there to be no match (and `search` will return `None` as you see).

Instead, you likely want [`<match>.end([<group>])`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end) or in your case, I think, `<match>.end()`.

For example, the following works for both lines:

```
import re
_task_global = re.compile(r'(\*+)([\w\s\dàé]+)(<[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+>)?', re.UNICODE)

text = '''* Apprendre à me servir de orgmode

** DONE Faire un script en python pour tester pygit2 :gd: :bfgd: #1215454'''

offset = 0
while True:
    tasks = _task_global.search(text, offset)
    if tasks is None: break
    print tasks.groups()
    #print tasks.endpos     # Don't use these...
    #offset = tasks.endpos
    print tasks.end()       # Use these
    offset = tasks.end()
```

Note I re-arranged your logic a bit, so make it more streamlined.

The output is:

```
('*', ' Apprendre \xc3\xa0 me servir de orgmode\n\n', None)
37
('**', ' DONE Faire un script en python pour tester pygit2 ', None)
90
```